# Why do we cut the tzitzit out of a tallit for a dead person?

Tags: death, tzitzis

I have seen that when one of our community elder died and when they put on tallit they cut out the tzitzit part and let him put only the garment. Why is this done to a dead person? Is there a source for this and a good reason ?

Comment: When visiting a grave people often tuck their tzitzis in as the dead can no longer perform mitzvos and could be mocking the dead

Comment: It is just as Dude said, and also some people like to keep at least one of the tzitzis from the deceased person's tallis for sentimental reasons.

Comment: http://forum.otzar.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=4374&mobile=on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source is from [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 351:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.351.2?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)

> אֵין קוֹבְרִין אֶת הַמֵּת אֶלָּא בְּטַלִּית שֶׁיֵּשׁ בּוֹ צִיצִית.
>   הַגָּה: וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּאֵין צָרִיךְ צִיצִית (טוּר בְּשֵׁם י''א).
>   וְנָהֲגוּ לְקָבְרוֹ בְּצִיצִית, אַךְ שֶׁפּוֹסְלִין תְּחִלָּה
>   הַצִּיצִית, אוֹ כּוֹרְכִין אֶחָד מִן הַכַּנְפוֹת.

The Shulchan Aruch writes that one buries a dead in a talit with tzitzit. The [Tur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arba%27ah_Turim) writes that some say one doesn't need tzitzit and the [Rema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Isserles) rules that one uses a talit but first invalidates one of the tzitzit.

[JVL](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/preparation_burial.html) comments this is indicating the deceased is no longer required to perform rituals.

Answer (score 0):

The Ramban (Milchamot Moed Katan 16a s.v. amar) argues that they should put tzitzit on the tallit that the deceased is buried in so that the deceased isn't embarrassed that he isn't wearing tzitzit when the resurrection of the dead takes places in the Messianic era. This opinion is codified by the Mechaber in Shulchan Aruch YD 351:2.

The Aruch HaShulchan (ad. loc.) brings that big sages like the Vilna Gaon instructed to be buried with kosher tzitzit but were prevented to do so by some spurious occurrences during the burial. This was taken by some to be a sign from heaven that the Rama should be followed and the tzitzis need to be invalidated right before the burial into the ground.

Answer (score -1):

Other sources note that it is improper to render the tallit pasul for when the meshiach arrives to raise us from the dead we must be prepared to once again assume our obligations.

Comment: What sources are these? Please edit to clarify

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Paul and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Hope to see you around!