# Sephardi burial in a talit

Tags: death, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, tzitzis, funeral-burial-levaya

In the [Shulchan Aruch (YD 351)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.351?lang=bi), the Mechebar writes that a man is buried in a talit with tzitzit, and the Rema adds that the tzitzit are made posul. Some googling (as well as checking with my local chevra kadisha), reveals that the Rema's position is a [common](http://jewishjournal.com/blogs/expiredandinspired/219800/jews-traditionally-buried-tallis-isaac-pollak/) [practice](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/preparation-for-burial), at least for Ashkenazim. What about Sephardim? Do they generally follow the Rema's opinion as well, or do they leave the tzitzit intact?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70110/why-do-we-cut-the-tzitzit-out-of-a-tallit-for-a-dead-person

Comment: Is there any reason not to assume that they follow the _Mechaber_ in this case?

Comment: [R. Tucazinsky](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Michel_Tucazinsky) wrote about this in his famous  Gesher HaChaim (vol. 2 [ch. 14](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31172&st=&pgnum=123)).