# Burial with Geniza

Tags: tallit-gadol, funeral-burial-levaya, genizah-storage

I once heard a Rav say that one way in which he disposes of his stash of Geniza is to bury it with the deceased if the family allows. He claimed that it was a segula (I can’t recall his source). I lately learned that this was prohibited as it pains the soul to see words of Torah (if the geniza contains holy books) while the deceased can no longer fulfill mitzvot. This being similar to why we tuck in our tzitziyot when we enter a cemetery. On the other hand, I also understand that some people get buried wrapped in their Talit. I’m all confused. Can someone please explain the issues at hand and cite specific Halacha.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70110/why-do-we-cut-the-tzitzit-out-of-a-tallit-for-a-dead-person https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47914/how-should-holy-objects-be-buried and this interesting quote https://www.vosizneias.com/52436/2010/04/01/lakewood-nj-sacred-items-burial-stirs-controversy/ "It is considered an honor to be buried with sacred texts, Rabbi Moshe Zev Weisberg said. "

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Lee and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Great question and +1. I answered the part on tzitzit here: [Why do we cut the tzitzit out of a tallit for a dead person?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70117/11501)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29979/759 Megillah 26b

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked all the sources listed in the various comments.

I can tell you from personal experience having been to a few more funerals, lately, than I would care for (I know people die. Never makes it easy when it's a relative or close friend :-(  ) that I have seen people come with bags of *sheimos* and bury them with the body. Almost all the burials I have been to have an Orthodox rav who not only doesn't object, but some of the *shaimos* are his own. So, apparently, there is no prohibition in doing this.

I would hope, though, that someone had asked the closest relative if doing this is fine with them. When we buried my mother in law, someone threw a bag of *sheimos* in there, and, from viewing my wife and sister-in-law's faces, they didn't seem pleased, as they were not informed beforehand. But, they were also too pre-occupied to object and make a fuss right there.

Comment: This perhaps just barely answers the question, which was "Can someone please explain the issues at hand and cite specific Halacha.".